# Javascript regular expression string-replacement of multi-line strings

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, multiline

With JavaScript regular expression replace, trying to replace anything between `<head>` and `</head>` tags so that:

```
<head>
   Multiline foo
</head>
<body>
  Multi line bar
</body>
```

gets replaced into:

```
<body>
  Multi line bar
</body>
```

and trying with the very basic: `<head(.*)\/head>/m` which doesn't work. It works fine when line breaks are removed from string. No matter what type of line breaks, what's the magic?

Comment: see http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/singleline-multiline-confusing

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the dot metacharacter doesn't match newlines.  In most regex flavors you can force it to match everything by setting "DOTALL" or "single-line" mode, but JavaScript doesn't support that.  Instead, you have to replace the dot with something that **does** match everything. The most common idiom is `[\s\S]` ("any whitespace character or any character that's *not* whitespace").

Comment: You also have `[\d\D]` and `[\w\W]`! :D

Answer (score 4):

Alan is right, to summarize, use `/<head([\s\S]*)\/head>/` and it should do what you wish.

The actual regex i'd use for the job is `/<head>([\s\S]*?)<\/head>/` but the difference probably won't matter, since it just assures there is no greedy matching with a 2nd head tag that should never be there :)